# Logical or of Django many to many queries returns duplicate results

Tags: python, sql, django, many-to-many

I have models with many to many relationships like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()

class Mail(models.Model):
    to = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='received_mails')
    cc = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name='cced_mails')
```

I want to obtain the set of contacts that are in either the to field or the cc field for a given email. Let's try:

```
>>> Contact.objects.filter(received_mails__id=111)
[<Contact: fred@foo.com>]
>>> Contact.objects.filter(cced_mails__id=111)
[<Contact: joe@bar.com>]
```

So far so good. We have one contact for each relationship. But it would be nice to get them both into the same QuerySet.

```
>>> Contact.objects.filter(Q(received_mails__id=111) | Q(cced_mails__id=111))
[<Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, <Contact: joe@bar.com>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

What happened? I have a feeling it is something to do with joining tables in SQL, but I don't really understand what is happening under the hood with many to many relationships. It could be that what I am trying to do is stupid, or that there is an easy way to do it. Either way, I'm happy to be set on the right path.

Edit: this is the query of the QuerySet:

```
SELECT `mailshareapp_contact`.`id`, `mailshareapp_contact`.`name`,
`mailshareapp_contact`.`address` FROM `mailshareapp_contact`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `mailshareapp_mail_to`
ON (`mailshareapp_contact`.`id` = `mailshareapp_mail_to`.`contact_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `mailshareapp_mail_cc`
ON (`mailshareapp_contact`.`id` = `mailshareapp_mail_cc`.`contact_id`)
WHERE (`mailshareapp_mail_to`.`mail_id` = 111
OR `mailshareapp_mail_cc`.`mail_id` = 111 )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As SQL returns all matching records, Django dutifully maps them to objects. What you're looking for is the `.distinct()` queryset method that makes SQL collapse all duplicate rows into one.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. (Sorry I can't vote you up yet.) This changes the query by using SELECT DISTINCT instead of just SELECT. I  don't see how you can get _so many_ duplicates without it, but my immediate problem is solved.

Comment: You will get a separate row for each combination of `mailshareapp_contact` × (`mailshareapp_mail_to` + `NULL`) × (`mailshareapp_mail_cc` + `NULL`) that satisfies at least one JOIN and one WHERE clause. By the way, if the above answers your question, you can always mark it as an accepted response.