# Duplicate instance returned in QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to create a method that filters questions based on tags which are only found in a particular user's questions. There is an issue with the QuerySet where it returns `Queryset([Question13, Question 14, Question13])`. Yet when the `.distinct()` is added it returns the desired result of `QuerySet([Question13, Question 14])`.

Why does the second chained `.filter()` method add the duplicate instance in the QuerySet?

```
class Post(Model):

    body = TextField()
    date = DateField(default=date.today)
    comment = ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    profile = ForeignKey(
        'authors.Profile', on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True,
        related_name='%(class)ss',
        related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )
    score = GenericRelation(
        'Vote', related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )


    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Question(Post):

    title = CharField(max_length=75)
    tags = ManyToManyField(
        'Tag', related_name="questions", related_query_name="question"
    )
    objects = Manager()
    postings = QuestionSearchManager()
```

```
class QuestionSearchManager(Manager):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def by_week(self, profile):
        today = date.today()
        weekago = today - timedelta(days=7)
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(
            date__range=(weekago, today)
        ).filter(tags__name__in=profile.questions.values_list(
            "tags__name", flat=True
        ))
        return queryset
```

*postings.json*

```
{
    "model": "posts.question",
    "pk": 13,
    "fields": {
        "body": "Content of Question 005",
        "date": "2022-02-12",
        "comment": null,
        "profile": 2,
        "title": "Question__005",
        "tags": [
            1,
            7
        ]
    }
},
{
    "model": "posts.question",
    "pk": 14,
    "fields": {
        "body": "Content of Question 006",
        "date": "2022-02-12",
        "comment": null,
        "profile": 3,
        "title": "Question__006",
        "tags": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This baffled me for a while also, but it is because of the related `tags` if the filter references multiple tags and those tags's property `name` you are now going to return a row per `tag` reference

`distinct` is your best friend when filtering using this `tags__name` style query.

No doubt that because it's a many to many relationship, this will be a common thing you need to be aware of when filtering on that relationship.

This is similar to this question:
[Logical or of Django many to many queries returns duplicate results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7740356/1184181)

You can also read this section of Django's docs to get a better idea how their queries work:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships